# What are the classes of posts?

Tags: discussion

I was reading a community wiki earlier today and came across something about how you couldn't edit comments because of their class. I would like to know these classes. I have not found an answer in any of those community wikis, and I was browsing in Incognito mode, so my history is gone.

*If you are answering, please put the classes in a number list*

Comment: You can edit comments, just not after five minutes. These classes do not exist formally; I suspect you may have heard the phrase "second class citizens" used to describe comments, because they are temporary and are often deleted.

Comment: @HDE226868 what I read was about others editing it.

Comment: Only moderators can edit (or delete) other users comments.

Comment: In short: "first class" posts are questions and answers. "second class", sometimes referred to as "third class" are the comments. And that's it. As the first comment says, it's not formal.